# Extracting stratigraphic profiles from multipatch features representing continuous geological formation in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: 3d-analyst, arcgis-pro, geology, multipatch

I have some multipatch undergroud layers representing each a specific geological formation unit. These units are vertically continuous and I'd like to "clip" them with an orthogonal plane to extract a vertical stratigraphic profile.
In order to do that, my simple idea was to:

1. draw one or more 2d lines representing the profile line seen from above.
2. extrude this by negative heights so that it goes through all the units.
3. convert the extruded line to multipatch.
4. merge the geological unit multipatches together.
5. use the multipatch from point 3. and 4. as input for [Intersect 3D](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/intersect-3d-3d-analyst-.htm).

So far, I was able to reach the final point, but I receive a warning message reading "WARNING 050084: No Intersect result generated", and no feature is returned. I guess the problem may arise from the multipatch in point 3. being "width-less" (flat) because derived from an extruded line. I cannot even close it, if this could be a problem. Below is an image to clarify what my data looks like (only two geological units are shown in this case).

Does anyone have any other idea on how to achieve this, or how to solve the warning?

[image: two geological units (blue, and ochre) and the extruded profile line (green)]